# Is it OK to ask questions for which you know the answer?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Just wondering, is it ok to ask questions if you know the answer already? I'm thinking that it helps the beta, but maybe I'm wrong on this?

Est-ce une bonne idée de poser des questions dont on connait déjà la réponse? A priori, je pense que ça peut aider la phase beta, mais ça me paraît quand même bizarre. Ou bien est-ce une mauvaise idée?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From SO [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions):

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! – phrase it in the form of a question.

Note also that this question has been [done to death](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answer+own+question) on meta.SO.

Comment: I should have looked first. Guess I was too focussed on the "beta" side of things and didn't realize it was a legitimate question even after that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this should be fine, as long as the question would have been on-topic even if you didn't know the answer.  Giving a good answer to a good question that you know beforehand can help the site be more useful.

Oui, il n'y a aucun problème avec ça, tant que la question serait appropriée pour le site même si on ne sait pas la bonne réponse.  Donner une bonne réponse à une bonne question qu'on sait déjà pourrait aider le site d'être plus utile.

Answer (score 1):

On occasion, I've asked a question, found out the answer AFTERWARD, and posted the answer days later. Apparently asking the question speeds up the learning process. And that would be a good thing.

The site gives a "self-learned" award to a person's answering their own question with three upvotes, so it is apparently encouraged.